# What should we do if the question is duplicate (is already answered) in other site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Specifically, I'm talking about [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1208842/how-to-make-excel-auto-calculate-contents-of-a-single-cell). But if possible, I want a more general guideline on questions that already has answers on other site.

**What should we do about these questions?**

Right now I'm thinking to migrate to the other site, then let them close as duplicate.

A less preferable option might be simply delete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What should we do about these questions?

Answer them. Don't delete questions just because they have an answer somewhere else.

Some advice:

1. We don't generally migrate questions to other sites if they are on-topic for Super User.
2. If there is an answer somewhere else on the Stack Exchange Network it can be used as a source reference for an answer on Super User, just like a source reference elsewhere on the internet.
3. Remember to follow the rules of attribution ([How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)).
4. Tailor the new answer to the question on Super User (don't just copy and paste the source answer).
5. Don't forget if it is your own question you can [Answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)